# Separate ROS android library

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is plenty of disparate info on ros.org about creating Android apps compatible with ROS. What I can't find (in any complete fashion) is whether or not there exists a stand-alone jar library which I can add to a Java (Eclipse) project that will let me send and receive ROS messages, without requireing a full rosjava install.

I found this but without more information I can't tell if it's close to what I'm looking for: http://www.ros.org/wiki/android

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12164/separate-ros-android-library/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-30**:
Please keep comments civil.  http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-11-30**:
I found this: https://vmi.lmt.ei.tum.de/projects/ros/wiki/Androidinstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what you're looking for.  A library which implements ROS communication protocols is a ROS library.  I suggest you look at [rosjava](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-12-05**:
... to provide some limited ROS compatibility with remote nodes, on a machine with a full ROS installation.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-12-05**:
I'm looking for "drop-in" ROS capability for mobile development. That is, I don't want to have to perform the entire ROS installation process (for various convenience reasons). Specifically, in the ideal case, I want a JAR that I can include in an Eclipse Android application...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also look at the sample Android projects here: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/?repo=android

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's become apparent that the capability for which I'm looking doesn't yet exist. Thanks for the direction, WG guys.

---

Originally posted by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) with karma: 753 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2